# Как срастить две таблицы с одинаковыми PrimaryKey

Tags: c#, .net

Есть таблицы с полем RowNumber, который является PrimaryKey, т.е. уникальный и только для чтения. Структуры таблиц одинаковые, а данные разные. Мне нужно, чтоб в одной таблице были данные двух таблиц. Значение RowNumber безразлично. В таблице есть по 3 строки. RowNumber что у первой, что у второй с 1 по 3.

```
table1
RowNumber   Data
------------------
  1         data 1
  2         data 2
  3         data 3

table2
RowNumber   Data
------------------
  1         data A
  2         data B
  3         data C

Необходимый результат
RowNumber   Data
------------------
  1         data 1
  2         data 2
  3         data 3
  4         data A
  5         data B
  6         data C
```

Если я делаю так

```
table1.Merge(table2);
```

то получаю в table1 то, что было в table 2. Если я пытаюсь в цикле добавлять строки из table2 в table1, то появляется исключение "Эта строка уже принадлежит другой таблице."

Кто знает, как объединить две таблицы с уникальным RowNumber. Содержимое RowNumber после слияния таблиц мне не важно, главное чтоб в одной таблице появились данные двух таблиц

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал следующим образом

```
long maxRowNum = table1.Rows.Count > 0 ? (long)table1.Compute("MAX(RowNumber)", string.Empty) : 0;
foreach (DataRow r in table2.Rows)
{
    var dr = r.ItemArray;
    dr[0] = ++maxRowNum;
    table1.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой код, пользуюсь им давно

```
public static void CopyRow(DataRow rowIn, DataRow rowOut, bool isAddOutColumns)
{
  foreach (DataColumn column in rowIn.Table.Columns)
  {
    if (!rowOut.Table.Columns.Contains(column.ColumnName))
    {
      if (!isAddOutColumns)
        continue;
      rowOut.Table.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
    }
    bool equals;/* = rowOut[column.ColumnName].GetType().Equals(rowIn[column.ColumnName].GetType());
    if (equals)
    {     */
      if (rowOut[column.ColumnName] is byte[] && rowIn[column.ColumnName] is byte[])
        equals = ((byte[])rowOut[column.ColumnName]).SequenceEqual((byte[])rowIn[column.ColumnName]);
      else
        equals = rowOut[column.ColumnName].Equals(rowIn[column.ColumnName]);
  /*  }        */
    if (!equals)
      try
      {
        rowOut[column.ColumnName] = rowIn[column.ColumnName];
      }
      catch
      {
      }
  }
}

public static void UnionTables(DataTable table, DataTable source, string uniqueName = "id", bool ReplaceIfDouble = true)
{
  DataView vSource = new DataView(source) { Sort = uniqueName };
  foreach (DataColumn column in source.Columns)
    if (!table.Columns.Contains(column.ColumnName))
      table.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
  DataView vTable = new DataView(table) { Sort = uniqueName };
  int iRow = 0;
  foreach (DataRowView rowSource in vSource) 
  {
    if (rowSource[uniqueName] == DBNull.Value) continue;
    IComparable idSource = (IComparable)rowSource[uniqueName];
    DataRow newRow = null;
    for (; iRow < vTable.Count; )
    {
      if (vTable[iRow][uniqueName] == DBNull.Value) { ++iRow; continue; }
      IComparable idTable = (IComparable)vTable[iRow][uniqueName];
      if (idTable.CompareTo(idSource) > 0)
        break;
      if (idTable.CompareTo(idSource) == 0)
      {
        if (ReplaceIfDouble && newRow == null)
        {
          newRow = vTable[iRow].Row;
          CopyRow(rowSource.Row, newRow, true);
        }
        else
          throw new Exception("Строка с таким ID уже существует");
      }
      ++iRow;
    }
    if (newRow == null)
    {
      newRow = table.NewRow();
      CopyRow(rowSource.Row, newRow, true);
      table.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
  }
}
```

Ваш случай

```
UnionTables(table1, table2, "RowNumber");
```

в table1 будут все данные, однако вам надо поменять название колонок Data на уникальные во всех таблицах

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не хотелось переименовывать столбцы и, показалось, слишком сложная реализация. Я нашёл ответ, опубликовал его как ответ на свой собственный вопрос